# Install Windows 7 from USB flash drive

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation, usb-flash-drive, community-faq

I have an [ISO image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) of the Windows 7 installation DVD, but I can't burn it to CD or DVD. I have an empty flash drive with plenty of space. Is there any way I can put the ISO image on it and install from it as if it were a CD?

Comment: http://www.isotousb.com is a simple tool for this purpose

Comment: @nateify This may also be a viable alternative/solution http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-78-1-from-your-phones-micro-sd-memory-card/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install windows 7 RC from a USB disk?](http://superuser.com/questions/1603/how-to-install-windows-7-rc-from-a-usb-disk)

Comment: @jiggunjer While I agree it's a duplicate, I closed the other (older one) as a duplicate of this one.  As this one is more complete and has better info.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Isn't this a good example where merging would work? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97076/merge-answers-but-not-question-when-closing-as-duplicate

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Microsoft has [released a tool](http://wudt.codeplex.com/) to put an ISO of Windows 7 on a bootable USB drive (or on a DVD).

Windows7Hacker has an explanation on where to download this tool and how to use it : [**Creating Bootable Windows 7 Install USB Flash Drive or DVD Using Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool**](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/10/creating-bootable-windows-7-install-usb-flash-drive-or-dvd-using-windows-7-usbdvd-download-tool/)

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know if one can install Grub2 loader to USB after creating this bootable USB? Would be nice to have a possibility to run Live Linux *or* install Windows.

Comment: @dma_k I'm sure it's possible. Haven't tried it, but you should be able to extract the bootloader from the iso and chainload it with GRUB.

Comment: Actually after I've created Windows installation flash, I've copied its' contents to Grub flash and used `ntldr /bootmgr` in config. It worked as a charm.

Comment: OS2Go https://www.easeus.com/system-to-go/how-to-install-windows-7-from-a-usb-flash-drive.html is a tool for this purpose

Answer (score 20):

Yes.

Easiest way is to mark a partition as active (although not always needed, depending on your motherboard).

Next, extract everything in the ISO to the root of the USB drive (use [Winrar](http://www.rarlabs.com), [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or your favourite extraction program.).

Reboot and either change boot order in the BIOS or press whatever key it is on your motherboard to bring up the boot menu (usually <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Esacpe</kbd>).

Choose USB drive.

Done!

Comment: Can you just quickly mention how to mark a USB drive partition as "active"; I've not heard of that before.

Comment: @Neil Barnwell, you simply go to disk management or any partition management tool and just set the drives partition to active in the same way as you would a hard drive. In Windows disk Management, right click and choose Active.

Comment: Your solution doesn't address making sure a proper boot sector exists on the USB key, which I believe is necessary for it to boot.  @Matthew Read's solution does address this.

Comment: Unfortunately, to us mere mortals, "marking a partition as active" is somehow not easy...as it were :)

Answer (score 12):

Use [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable USB flash drive with the ISO.

The software was made for creating bootable linux flash drives, but works with any bootable ISO.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't detect my Transcend 250GB external HDD :(

Comment: @Bogdan0x400, open the command prompt, cd to the folder where unetbootin.exe is located and start it with the option "targetdrive=f:"
`unetbootin targetdrive=f:"` (replace "f:" with your drive's letter)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, in four easy steps:

1. Using the [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://www.bootdisk.com/plan040109/hpflash1.zip) (v2.0.6), format the flash drive using FAT32 leaving all the boxes unchecked.
2. Mount the Windows 7 ISO image using [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com) (a free tool).
3. Then copy the contents of the ISO image (all of the Windows 7 files and folders) over to the flash drive. Grab a cup of coffee; it could take upwards of 5-10 minutes.
4. Lastly, rename the file on the root of the flash drive from "BOOTMGR" to "NTLDR".

---

I hope this helps...

Comment: Almost a copy of my answer, anyway - I don't think step 4 is needed - I have never needed to rename anything and I do not recommend step 2. Any sort of Virtual drive program installs a driver which will always be running and slow your machine (although not exactly by a lot, and I do like virtual clone drive). If this is a one off job, it is much better just to use Winrar or 7 zip as I said. It will dothe same job and will not do anything to the system.

Comment: I don't understand how it is almost a copy of your answer, anyway - thanks for the critique...  lol

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a few years old, but I think this program is worth mentioning (it's also easy).
[Your Universal Multiboot Integrator](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)
[image: YUMI Multiboot USB Creator]
You can use it to add many Operating Systems on one flash drive (both Windows and Linux, I don't know about MAC OSX)
You can also use it to add other ISO images, like Norton Ghost SRD, Acronis True Image and many other tools.
[image: YUMI list of available ISOs!]

Comment: Windows only :|

Answer (score 1):

I love using rufus for extracting any OS onto a USB. It's source is on github as well.  For windows:

[Rufus Source on GitHub](https://rufus.ie/)

[image: Rufus UI]

Answer (score 1):

If already running Windows™ you can simply use the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool from Microsoft](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool).

If on another OS you can perform the following steps:

1. Make sure the filesystem is NTFS and has the bootable flag set..
2. Use [ms-sys](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/) to write boot record (`ms-sys -7 /dev/sdx`).
3. Mount the ISO and copy all the files and directories.