# Installing Windows 7 on a netbook using SanDisk USB Cruzer

Tags: windows-7, usb, partitioning, netbook, usb-flash-drive

I have this weird problem with my SanDisk USB Cruzer maybe someone can help me...

1. I removed U3 software
2. I used diskpart.exe to "activate" my partition

yet when I restart my computer and select to boot off of USB it won't boot, my computer freezes and nothing is happening after that.

any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What have you done to make it bootable?

Comment: i've used diskpart.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a partition to active is not enough to boot from it.  You also need a bootloader installed to the MBR (aka sector 0) of the device.  The bootloader is the code that tells the computer how to boot an operating system.

More than likely, your system "freezes" because you told it to boot from the device and there's no code there for it to boot from.  Please see the earlier question ["Install Win7 from USB"](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-win7-from-usb) for how to make a Win7 install thumbdrive.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) (as I use it always). Always worked, clickety-click, really easy to use.