# Fresh windows 7 install FROM a portable HD / Passport HD

Tags: windows, installation, portable-harddrive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Windows 7 through USB Drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/113153/install-windows-7-through-usb-drive)

I have a portable HD and i want to install windows 7 from it as i have no USB or cd to work with. Is this do-able?

I have so far made a seperate partition on the drive and made it bootable but it doesn't seem to get recognized when i boot it up. Any ideas?

Also what would the boot option be under the boot section? USB - HDD right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you marked the partition as active?

If you have, I would just make sure that when you reboot, you select the hard drive as the bootable device.

If it doesn't show up, it is possible that your BIOS doesn't support boot from USB.

If it does show up, it is possible you didn't correctly setup the hard drive.

Please try that and then report back and I will try to give you some more help.

As for what the boot option would be, it changes from device to device... That does sound right, but, I can't guarantee it.

Comment: My bios should support it as i have previously installed windows 7 from a usb flash drive, my current problem is that no matter what i option i choose it simply skips and loads the current OS from the hard drive. I have made the device bootable and such but no luck. (Yes i have already makred the partition as active).