# How to install Windows (x86/x64) on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, usb, iso-image

I installed Ubuntu edition (10.04) on my windows 7, completely eliminating it to the original installation. After I was forced to reverse the process, but could not find tools or explanations of how to do it.

To clarify the equipment, it is: a netbook, acer, no optical drive cd / dvd, the process should be fully via USB.

I hope I was clear enough, count on the support of you. Thank you.

--

Instalei a edição Ubuntu (10.04) sobre meu Windows 7, eliminando completamente a a instalação original. Depois fui forçado à reverter o processo, mas não encontrei ferramentas ou explicações de como fazê-lo.

Para esclarecer sobre o equipamento, trata-se de: um netbook, acer, sem leitor óptico de cd/dvd, o processo deverá ser totalmente via USB.

Espero ter sido bastante claro, conto com o suporte de vocês.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: this sounds like a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-win7-from-usb ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid having to buy a DVD drive, grab your installation DVD and a USB drive with at least the same capacity as the installation disk. On any other Windows Vista or 7 computer,  follow [this guide](http://experiortech.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/burn-windows-vista-or-7-iso-to-usb-flash-drive/) for copying the install disc onto a USB drive. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**If you just wanted to reinstall windows**, I would suggest getting a [USB DVD drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827139050&cm_re=USB_DVD_drive-_-27-139-050-_-Product), and use your "reinstallation DVD's" that came with your netbook.

**If your trying to recover all the original data on your netbook**, you'll find yourself in a very difficult position.  Start by cloning your existing disk or putting in a new harddrive (very difficult with a netbook, and in some cases impossible)

1. Mirror the Disk, or get a second harddrive.
2. Install your new operating system on the new system.
3. Using Data recovery software such as [UFS Explorer](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/), Try and recover all the files you can.

Once data has been overwritten, it becomes very difficult to restore data. Since you completed the install of  Ubuntu, you've overwritten areas of the harddrive and recovering files from there will be troublesome.

GOOD LUCK!