# Can you run a .iso from a flash drive or external hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, computer-building, iso-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Win7 from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-win7-from-usb)

I'm currently in the process of building a computer (parts in the mail from newegg, should be fun) and since I need an OS, I figured I's take advantage of my student status to download a copy of windows 7 from the MSDN Academic Alliance.

Anyway, that download left me with a .iso file. One problem -- the .iso is too large to burn to a CD (it's 3 gigs, or so, I believe). So my question becomes, what's the best way to install the OS? Do I need to procure a DVD burner / blank DVD ? Is it possible to mount the .iso on a virtual drive on my external harddrive (via daemon tools or the like) and then install from that?

What's my best option?

Edit: .iso is not 15 gigs, the "Install space required" is 15 gigs. >.< .iso itself is just 3...

Comment: Can you verify the size? Windows 7 isn't 15GB, it fits on a single layer DVD, which is 4.7GB

Comment: If it's really 15GB, you won't be able to burn it to a DVD either (Blu Ray? Probably; I don't have one so I'm not positive). I have a feeling it's a bit smaller than that, though.

Comment: Yeah, not to be redundant, but yeah ;-) I'd say your best option is to go back and double-check the size, and if it's really 15 GB, complain to Microsoft that you got the wrong file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps from the following site to copy the ISO to a flash drive and install it from there:

[Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool)

(I'm not sure, but if you purchased an Upgrade version of Windows 7, you *might not* be able to reboot via USB or DVD drive and install it; you may be required to mount the ISO and install it from your current O/S.)

If you're not trying to boot up via a flash drive and install from there, it's *much* easier just to mount the ISO and install it from the mount while using your current O/S.