# Make a bootable pen drive for windows?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, formatting, usb-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Win7 from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-win7-from-usb)

I want to format my laptop through a pen drive. I want to make my pen drive bootable for windows as I don't have a CD burner. Also, my laptop currently does not have an operating system installed.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered innumerable times. Take a look at [Install Win7 from USB](http://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-win7-from-usb), for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without an operating system installed of course. What you can do is, take your Windows CD/DVD (or virtual ISO image) to one of your friend's computer and then use [THIS UTILITY](http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool) to make a bootable USB drive out of that, easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need a second working computer with an optical drive to create the pen drive.  Here's a [how to for Windows 7](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that [PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) is the easiest and most versatile Bootable flash USB drive software.  You can boot a windows installation straight from there.  All that is needed is the ISO of the Windows OS.  This means that you'll need a second PC.  If the second PC is a windows 7 [this](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/windowsexperience/archive/2009/04/13/burn-iso-images-natively-in-windows-7.aspx) guide will be helpful in creating a ISO of a cd natively from windows 7.  If you don't have windows 7 you'll have to use third party software (i.e. Nero, Roxio, or any of the free options that are out there)

This [guide](http://howdoi-tech.blogspot.com/2010/09/bootable-usb-flash-drive-pc-repair-kit.html) is how to use PenDriveLinux.  It does not specify the Windows installation, but can easily be adapted to suit your needs.