# How can I install a Windows 7 into BootCamp via USB

Tags: windows-7, mac, macbook, boot-camp

I have a MacBook and I'd like to install Windows 7 via USB. I've created the partition using Boot Camp and I've got an .ISO of my Windows 7 install disk. Is it possible to install this via USB, instead of burning a DVD?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Through Disk Utility you can restore the Windows 7 ISO onto the flash drive.
When you hold option at startup to access the boot options the disc will appear.

**Note:** When you do the restore through Disk Utlity make sure your flash drive is partitioned correctly.

[image]

It needs to be partitioned as Mac OS X journaled (HFS+) - this will enable the GUID partition map (so the boot menu can read the ISO). Next, click source and within the finder locate the ISO and you're set.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm partitioning my disk with 1 partition as 'Max OS Extended (Journaled)', but when I try to select the ISO in the Source: field, the iso file is greyed out by Finder, and attempting to do it by drag-and-drop gives 'Could not validate source - Invalid argument'. Also, I'm on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 8):

With Lion, Apple has added an option to BootCamp that will create a bootable USB Windows 7 install disk, this option is only enabled in Mac models which don't have an optical drive. To enable this option just follow [this guide](http://www.codez4mac.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=212&t=61921).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'll take it into consideration for my following answers.

Comment: I don't know if it's a Mountain Lion thing, but I cannot modify the plist file. Even sudo won't cut it as the file is "locked".

Comment: @Aviel - Please include the relevant information from your link..  This is an excellent chance for somebody, to find the content that was at that link, and submit a new proper answer.

Comment: It looks like that link is dead. Or at least it's going to a very sketchy looking site with no obvious link to the information.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

[Burn ISO to bootable USB flash drive in Mac OSX terminal (via command line Diskutil)](http://www.nightlionsecurity.com/blog/guides/2011/07/burn-iso-to-bootable-usb-flash-drive-in-mac-osx-terminal-via-command-line-diskutil/#.UXA-bmQY2Jd)

> - Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of hdiutil (e.g., `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso`)
> - Note: OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.
> - Run `diskutil list` to get the current list of devices
> - Insert your flash media
> - Run `diskutil list` again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. /dev/disk2)
> - Run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN` (replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2)
> - Execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` (replace N with your disk number)
> - Run `diskutil eject /dev/diskN` and remove your flash media when the command completes

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to run the Bootcamp assistant before you try to boot off the flash drive. Follow the instructions in [How to install Windows 7 from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb), then see if the computer will recognize the flash drive when you boot up. To choose different boot media when a Mac starts, press  <kbd>Option</kbd>, then select the flash drive if it appears.

If that doesn't work, post in the comments; there may be more steps required to get it to boot off of the external drive.