# Installing Windows 7 from external hard drive?

Tags: boot, external-hard-drive

I built my first gaming rig. It's on the way. My school gives us access to MSDN which has bunch of OS on there and we can download it for free. I don't have any blank DVD discs with me here. Is it possible to download the .iso file to my external hard drive and install Windows from there?

Here are the specs if you were wondering:

Case: Antec Nine Hundred Black Steel ATX Mid Tower Computer Case
CPU: Intel Core i5-2500K Sandy Bridge 3.3GHz
RAM: G.SKILL Sniper 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3
GPU: GBABYTE GV-R695UD-1GD Radeon HD 6950 1GB 256-bit GDDR5
PSU: Antec EarthWatts EA-650 GREEN 650W ATX12V v2.3 SLI Ready CrossFire Certified 80 PLUS
MOTHERBOARD: MSI P67A-G43 (B3) LGA 1155 Intel P67 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0
HARD DRIVE: SAMSUNG Spinpoint F3 HD103SJ 1TB 7200 RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s 3.5"
CD-ROM: LITE-ON CD/DVD Burner - Bulk Black SATA Model

Edit: It didn't work. I tried the Windows tool but it didn't recognize my external HDD. I also formatted my exHDD to FAT32 and that also didn't work. I don't have a thumb driver larger than 1 GB. Anyway I'll go buy a blank DVD tomorrow morning. Thanks again.

Comment: Check out the answers on [Install Windows 7 from USB](http://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb). The methods listed there will probably work for what you need to do. If none of those methods work, edit your question to say why, and if they do, then let us know in the comments here and we can mark your question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

There was a tool that Microsoft were distributing to put the Win7 DVD on to a USB stick for installing on netbooks, there is a reference to it and a guide here http://www.intowindows.com/download-windows-7-usbdvd-download-tool-from-microsoft/