# Fresh windows 7 install FROM a USB portable HD / Passport HD

Tags: windows, usb, installation, portable-harddrive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Windows 7 from a USB Hard Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/299889/installing-windows-7-from-a-usb-hard-drive)

I have a portable HD and i want to install windows 7 from it as i have no USB or cd to work with. Is this do-able?

I have so far made a seperate partition on the drive and made it bootable but it doesn't seem to get recognized when i boot it up. Any ideas?

Also what would the boot option be under the boot section? USB - HDD right?

Extra - "
My bios should support it as i have previously installed windows 7 from a usb flash drive, my current problem is that no matter what i option i choose it simply skips and loads the current OS from the hard drive. I have made the device bootable and such but no luck. (Yes i have already makred the partition as active)."

P.S. Can you not close this as it is NOT an exact duplicate... that other question is for a usb FLASH drive not a HD.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's USB flash disk or HD. Microsoft USB tool will do it. [Install Windows 7 from USB flash drive](http://superuser.com/a/62230/4377)

Comment: Ensure that once your USB HDD is detected in the BIOS as such that it doesn't end up second in order in your 'hard drives' list in the BIOS boot ordering (this depends highly on the BIOS involved, and for us to guess what BIOS options you have is kind of tough. ;) ).  Perhaps unhook your existing internal drive until you're sure you can boot off that USB drive while it's the only drive in the system.

Comment: Most probably dup of http://superuser.com/questions/299889/installing-windows-7-from-a-usb-hard-drive, which already has an accepted answer. (The other Q is kind of mixup of two things, but it will be hopefully split soon.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend www.pendrivelinux.com. As long as you have an .iso file of your OS (you can create one as well with utilities found on the internet), you can make a bootable USB device with this software that has your installation media on it for Windows 7.