# How to perform a clean install of Windows 7 on New Netbook without CD?

Tags: windows-7, installation, netbook, usb-flash-drive, bloatware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Windows 7 from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb)

I got a new netbook which came pre-installed with Windows 7 Starter and full of promotional crapware.

I am interested in somehow extracting the clean portion of Windows 7 on that netbook, saving it to a USB disk, then wiping out the entire drive and then installing this clean Windows 7 only, without all the bagage.

How do I do that? Is there a step-by-step guide that allows me to perform this safely?

If this helps, the netbook model is `Acer aspire one D255E`.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution without violating the EULA for the Windows 7 software - you couldn't do much with the install in place and you would have to resort to somehow modifying the recovery partition / media. The recovery media from Acer/Gateway/Emachines includes all the crapware on the main restore disc / partition. You could just remove the programs... you're not going to have issues doing so...

Comment: @Dustin G. What are you talking about? Violating the EULA?? As long as he has a legal key, which I am assuming he has one affixed to the computer since it is new, he is entitled to the software, and to reinstall it. By your reasoning, if the computer died, and he reinstalled, he is violating the EULA? His only real issue is finding a DVD with Windows 7 Starter on it. He can get that however he wants...even from a torrent site. The only thing that counts is that he has a legal license.

Comment: Thank you all. In my searches I also found this [Aspire One specific guide](http://www.osnews.com/story/20795/Installing_Windows_7_on_the_Aspire_One_or_Any_Other_Netbook). Now I need to make sure that I can always resort to the recovery partition, should I want to sell this netbook in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Create a partition on a thumb drive:**

1. First, you’ll need the DiskPart utility on the system you will use to prep the thumb drive. This is a free disk partitioning utility that is likely already installed on your Windows system. If not, you can download DiskPart here.
2. Launch the DiskPart utility by typing diskpart at the Start Menu.
3. Then run the list disk command to check the status of your drive.
4. Now run select disk 1 where the "1" is actually the corresponding number of your USB drive.
5. Run clean.
6. Once the thumb drive is clean, you can run create partition primary.
7. Now make the partition active by entering active.

**Format the partition by FAT32 and assign a letter:**

8. Then you need to set up the file system as Fat32 by running format fs=fat32 quick (quick, of course, specifies that you want to perform a quick format to speed up the process).
9. Entering the assign command gives the USB drive a drive letter, making it easy to access from Windows Explorer

**Copy the installation files onto the thumb drive:**

10. Then you can copy everything from the Windows 7 installation DVD onto the USB key (a simple drag and drop will do).
11. Now you can insert the thumb drive into the system you want to install Windows 7 onto and boot the system. The installation will now proceed as usual—but faster.

Answer (score 0):

an00b, Other than your data, there is probably not much that you can copy to a USB drive that will probably help you unless there is a recovery partition.

The easiest way would be to see it you can get a Windows 7 Starter DVD, possibly from the manufacturer (for about $20 usually), and then you can reinstall with your legal key, which is affixed to the computer.

In the alternative, if you have any friends with TechNet or MSDN, you can legally use the ISO images they can download there to make a DVD. Your key is what gives you the right to use Windows, not the DVD. You could then use that to create a bootable USB drive if you don't have an external DVD player.

Comment: Read this: http://www.computing.net/answers/thelounge/netbook-restore-disks/739.html You may be able to create your disks from within your computer right now, but if not, this guy called Acer, complained, and they sent him the $21 disks for free. Of course, that may come with the crapware (who knows unless you actually have it)...you want the clean Microsoft OEM Windows 7 Starter DVD.

Comment: http://www.windowsvalley.com/unlock-all-editions-from-windows-7-iso-image-x86-and-x64/

Comment: as I know, you can obtain the Window 7 Starter (or whatever you need) everywere you want (even on Rapidshare) when you have a legal key for that version. It should not be problem to activate it. It is a common recommendation in my country when asking questions like this or in case or DVD damage or recovery partition deletion: "get the same Win version you have, does not matter if from some warez site or burned copy from friend, and activate it using your key."