# (How) can I split the Windows 8 Dev Preview + Dev Tools ISO in 2 DVD's?

Tags: iso-image, dvd-burning, windows-8-preview

I downloaded the W8DP with Developer tools, but it's 4.8 Gb, just to taunt me (as standard capacity DVD's are 4.7 Gb).

Is it possible to split it on 2 CD's? Or if not, how would I install it?

I would run it in a VM (like VirtualBox), but my CPU doesn't support 64-bit emulation, so I can't.

While waiting for the answer, I'll download the (puny) 32-bit non-dev preview, just in case it's impossible.

Comment: You can download visual studio express 11 separately from MSDN subscription downloads, but why bother, get a large USB disk

Comment: Or srping for some Dual Layer DVD's.

Answer (score 4):

[Install Windows 8 from a USB stick](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2011/09/install-windows-8-from-a-usb-stick/)

Comment: I agree - use a USB stick - the tool Microsoft released to copy the Windows 7 DVD to USB sticks works great - I used it to put the ISO on a USB flash drive then proceeded to install Windows 8 on a 4+ year old computer in UNDER 10 minutes.

Comment: I did forget to mention that my biggest USB stick at hand is of 4 Gb too. Any other idea?

Comment: That's just why I bought 8 GB stick some time ago ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have several options of other media that can support the size requirement:

- Boot from [a USB stick](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive) (and [download.cnet.com link](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool/3000-18513_4-10972600.html))
- A portable HD (same guide as USB stick)
- [Dual Layer DVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-R_DL)
- [Blu-ray Disc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray_Disc), requires expensive disc and a blu-ray drive.

Comment: Installed it from an external hdd today. worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Or you can install whatever version you like and then install the [FULL VERSION of Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/search.aspx?q=Microsoft%C2%AE%20Visual%20Studio%C2%AE%2011%20Developer%20Preview). The Win8x64withTools ISO only has the express edition.

I don't think most people realize that you don't have to have MSDN to get the full VS11 preview. And the full version will even install on Windows 7, although on my quick look it doesn't seem to have the WinRT 'Metro-style' stuff in a Win7 install. I can't answer if there are WinRT/Metro templates if you install it on Win8.