# How do I make a bootable USB with Windows 8?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Windows 8 from USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/336638/how-to-install-windows-8-from-usb-flash-drive)

How do I make a bootable USB with Windows 8? I would like to install it on my device with a broken DVD device. Has anyone faced this situation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Microsoft USB/DVD tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) is very easy to use, you need 4GB flash drive and original untouched ISO image. You can obtain them for now from MSDN, Technet and some other places, just make sure to check the SHA of the ISO file.

Comment: Will this work with the retail Windows 8 Pro, i.e. an upgrade?

Comment: Upgrade windows 8 differs only in license. Not code, so no reason it should not work.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) 100% free and support all of operating systems. 
Here is [User Guide Link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to the USB tools (or can't use them because your removable drive shows up as a `local disk`)  it is possible to make a bootable USB drive with only the Windows 8 ISO and a working Windows machine.

1. Mount or extract the files from your Windows 8 ISO
2. Open windows console ( Start > type `cmd` into the search field or click run > `cmd` | Right-click `cmd` and select `Run as Administrator` -- Vista or 7 only)
3. With the console open enter `diskpart` and then `list disk`; locate your USB drive here
4. `select disk ?`  (? Is the number of your drive found from `list disk` )
5. `clean`
6. `create partition primary`
7. `select partition 1`
8. `active`
9. `format fs=ntfs quick`
10. `exit`
11. Type `cd` followed by the directory of extracted ISO files OR just type in the letter of the drive where your ISO is mounted (i.e `cd C:\Users\me\Downloads\Win8` or `g:`)
12. `cd boot`
13. `bootsect /nt60 ?:` Where ? is the letter of your USB drive. If you get an error about the wrong architecture you need to find the 32bit bootsect.exe (you can even use the 32bit Windows 7 file) program to run this command.
14. Copy all of the files from the ISO to your USB drive
15. Reboot with the USB drive plugged into your computer and make sure the motherboard is set to boot from USB.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft USB/DVD tool does not work on some systems. So I used the following tool to create a bootable Windows 8 USB drive. This tool can be used to create only bootable USB drives, not a DVD.

Download [Win8USB - Windows 8 USB Installer Maker](http://apps.codigobit.info/2012/03/windows-8-usb-installer-maker.html).

- Use a pendrive with at least 4 GB free space.
- Select the USB drive to use and the ISO  file of the OS then proceed to create.

Here are some screenshots

[image]

[image]