# How to make bootable USB device

Tags: windows-8, usb

I want to make Bootable USB device to install windows 8 on my pc. Please suggest most easiest way to this. 
Any software available to that?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/476927/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-with-windows-8?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a lot of software exist to do this:

- Unetbootin : https://unetbootin.github.io
- Yumi (my favorite) : https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/
- of course the Windows USB/DVD Download Tool available on codeplex...

Comment: while we are listing favorites: RUFUS  https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: @JyotiKumari it might be worth stating which one worked and what task you were using it for.