# How can I reinstall Windows 7 without an optical drive?

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Windows 7 from USB flash drive](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive)

My wife has a Neo netbook with a manufacturer installed Windows 7 OS.

Is it possible to reinstall the OS without an optical drive, perhaps with a USB memory and the license code on the Windows sticker?

Comment: Similar to what Paul suggests, but I just saw that you don't seem to have an installation file as well?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.iso` file sold from the Windows website. If you take this route, it may cost a few bucks, but you can use [WUDT](http://wudt.codeplex.com/) to create a bootable USB drive, and then you are solid if you ever need to do it again.

Just be careful to modify your boot order in BIOS.