# How to Install Windows 7/ XP from the network

Tags: windows, windows-installation

I have 2 computers, but no Windows DVD

1st Computer is a new one - totally Blank. (Saw an option in BIOS to boot from network.)

2nd Computer is working and has ISO images of Windows XP and Windows7. I would like to install either Windows 7 or XP on the 1st computer. How do I do that? I want to install it via the Network.

Also is there some way to do this through USB?

Comment: Both methods are relatively complicated considering you have just an ISO file. Both would require breaking the ISO down, a pre-boot environment, among other things. Burning it to a CD would be much faster & easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous guides to installing Windows 7 from a USB.

[Install Windows 7 from USB flash drive](https://superuser.com/q/62193/24500)