# How to erase Ubuntu & install Windows Vista using USB

Tags: windows-vista, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Windows 7 from USB flash drive](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive)

I want to install Windows Vista erasing currently installed Ubuntu. My CD/DVD-drive isn't working and if I connect external CD/DVD drive, it's also not getting detected in boot time. The only option I'm left with is USB-installation.

Now I have a laptop with Ubuntu, a Windows Vista Original DVD and a USB drive. I want to install Windows Vista onto my laptop. Is there any way to install with the resources I have. Please help me to crack this out. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions at http://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive

Comment: Thanx for the link @Mokubai

Comment: Did that solution work for you @Rahul? Else I'll close it as a duplicate of that question

Comment: @Ivo Flipse I was out of reach weekend. I'll try today & update you. Thanks.

Comment: @IvoFlipse Dude it worked. I installed using USB. By just copying all the DVD contents into formatted USB worked. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @Rahul, glad it worked :-)