# How can I create a bootable stick with Windows?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Windows 7 from USB flash drive](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive)

with linux distributions is possible. Can this be done with windows too?

Basically I just want to move the files from my installation DVD to a stick, and make it bootable like the dvd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

http://wintoflash.com/download/en/

Answer (score 4):

The official way is to use the [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool).

> If you choose to download an ISO file (so that you can create a bootable file from a DVD or USB flash drive), copy your Windows 7 ISO file onto your media and, run the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool. After you do this, you can install Windows 7 onto your computer directly from the USB flash drive or DVD.

Presumably it will still work if you create an `iso` file from a physical DVD rather than downloading it from Microsoft.