# How can you install Windows 7 on a MacBook Pro without DVD drive?

Tags: windows-7, macbook, dvd

I'm wondering whether will be possible to install Windows 7 on a Boot Camp partition with the new MacBook Pro Retina. The DVD drive is not available and I don't know any workaround to install Windows there.

Comment: -1: Your question does not show research effort.  There are ways to install Windows from a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question: Yes, it's possible.

You can install Windows [from a USB drive](https://superuser.com/q/62193/48078) as well. No need for a DVD. The procedure is similar to the one [with a MacBook Air](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20020513-285/install-win-7-on-macbook-air-from-a-usb-drive/).