# I lost my windows 7 CD and my hard drive was cleared. What should I do?

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation, boot, format

> **Related Questions:**
>   [Install Windows 7 from USB flash drive](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive)
>   [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/q/272141/)

I'm trying to boot from an old Vista disk but I'm not getting anywhere. I think my best bet is trying to install windows from a usb instead. How would I go about doing that? Like I said, when my computer boots up I can't get anywhere since the hard drive is formatted. Thanks!

Comment: "not getting anywhere" will not help. Can you provide more info on what happens when you try and boot from the Vista disk? BTW, do you have a Vista key to do the install? Windows 7 key? Is this a computer with a recovery partition?

Comment: See [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD](http://superuser.com/q/272141/) and [Install Windows 7 from USB drive](http://superuser.com/q/62193/). You will still need your original Windows 7 license key, but should be able to reinstall using those tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from any lan computer or usb too but for that you have to change your boot priority. You will find it in the bios settings. But to boot from usb you need a bootable usb drive having bootable iso file of ur OS.