# CHKDSK error code 766f6c756d652e63 3f1

Tags: windows, chkdsk

On a Windows 7 computer, running `chkdsk /r /f C:` in repair mode, it gives the error, `Unspecified error 766f6c756d652e63 3f1.` or something like that. I have tried the following:

- uninstalling all antivirus software
- scanning with MalwareByte's Anti-Malware
- doing a Disk Cleanup
- running Disk Defrag
- booting TRK and running `fsck -t ntfs` (gives error `Unsupported case.` and `not implemented`).

I have also tried a System Restore, but there is a Temporary Internet file that appears to be in all restore points, and that file must be corrupted or something, because System Restore always grinds to a halt when it gets to that file.

What should I try next? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean?

Comment: Check your HDD for errors using its manufacturer's utility. If your HDD has bad sectors (since you ran chkdsk /r), best to copy as much data off it as possible and replace the disk. Moreover, if it has bad sectors, stressing it further with defrag before getting your data off it is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Karan The problem has existed for a long time, and no files seem to be missing. Do you think that this error indicates a **hardware** failure?

Comment: `chkdsk /r /f C: in repair mode, it gives the error, Unspecified error 766f6c756d652e63 3f1. … booting TRK and running fsck -t ntfs (gives error Unsupported case. and not implemented).`   Hmm, it sounds like your file-system is damaged/corrupted. What you can try is to use a partition-management program to check the volume and possible repair it. Otherwise, you may want to copy your data (hopefully you won’t need to resort to a data-recovery program) and wipe it.

Comment: @Synetech It sounded to me like fsck.ntfs is not fully implemented. It gave function names before the not implemented errors. EDIT But I admit, the unsupported case error would sound like the FS has some corrupt data. My guess is corrupted metadata?

Comment: Why specifically are you using the /r switch if you're not sure whether it's a hardware error or not?

Comment: @Karan, I agree with Benji. If it were an issue with bad sectors, then `chkdsk` would have said so because it is designed to detect such problems, but it is crashing instead. He’s probably using the `/r` switch because people always keeps saying to do it for every problem (just like how people keep saying to reinstall/repair-install for everything).

Comment: @Synetech: I assumed the disk had bad sectors precisely because /r is being used. Since it locates bad sectors and recovers readable information, why else would one use that switch? If there's some other problem such as a corrupted file system, a reinstall should fix it.

Comment: @Karan, I just answered that above.

Comment: @Karan I'm using the /r switch because if I do `chkdsk` it says `Errors found. Cannot continue in read-only mode.`

Comment: @BenjiWiebe, then use the `/f` switch.

Comment: @Synetech I used the following commands, in the following order: `chkdsk` (said could not continue in read-only mode), `chkdsk /f` (gave error code in title), `chkdsk /r /f` (same), `chkdsk /r /r /x` (same)

Comment: You said that you uninstalled stuff, ran scans, etc. Does that mean that you can boot and access files?

Comment: @Synetech Yes the comp works fine(?) except for the problem with `chkdsk`. The disk should be checked, because `chkdsk C:` says `Errors found...`

Comment: Should this be moved to chat?

Comment: `the comp works fine`   Then you may be best off copying your files somewhere, then wiping the disk and copying back. If so, make sure to copy just the files; do not clone the disk because it might copy the corruption as well. You may also want to use a tool to wipe the first couple of thousand clusters before re-creating a partition to get rid of any bad stuff that may have found its way in there somehow.

Comment: @Synetech How do I do that with out the Windows Installation disk? Wipe the disk... and install Linux? In this case, that is not an option.

Comment: [Run Startup Repair](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproperf/thread/a27a8e67-bdb5-4499-948d-072c0d8930c4) from the [Win7 DVD](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Startup-Repair-frequently-asked-questions) and see if that helps. Edit: Ah, no disc? Can't you borrow one from somewhere?

Comment: @Karan This comp came from Walmart (or was it BestBuy?)... No disks at all came with it.

Comment: @Karan And I did run Startup Repair by tapping F8 while starting the comp, and selecting repair your computer, logging in, and starting startup repair. It said it was repairing the disk, it will take several hours, and then 10secs later it was done. Everything was the same before and after.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe if you don't have an installation CD, you can [download a Windows 7 ISO](http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd) and then [put it on a flash drive](http://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive), and use that to try to run a disk recovery. You can also use the built-in backup and restore functionality to back up all your data, then format the hard drive and replace it all. Make sure to separately back up any really important files yourself first.

Comment: `How do I do that with out the Windows Installation disk? Wipe the disk... and install Linux? In this case, that is not an option. … This comp came from Walmart (or was it BestBuy?)... No disks at all came with it.`   @BenjiWiebe, you never mentioned that. In this case, you should be able to restore to factory settings by using the recovery partition on the disk. Check your manual to find out how.

Comment: Do you have more than one volume? [This person said](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproperf/thread/da446ba3-e426-4250-884b-8d3e06856910) that the error was because the drive was assigned a different letter in Recovery mode and that simply using the correct letter fixed it.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe, so do you have multiple volumes? Did you try checking the drive letter?

Comment: @Synetech There are two volumes: C: and a recovery partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/disc-check-error-766f6c756d652e63-3f1/7022ff97-00bb-4ae8-a75e-e9a92bee76d8) might help. It has an answer from a Windows Support Engineer and he suggests starting the computer in Windows Recovery (WinRE) mode.

Comment: In the very first line of the question, he said he already did that: `On a Windows 7 computer, running chkdsk /r /f C: in repair mode…`

Comment: I already did that... I have already come across that post that the link goes to. I think this may be the correct answer in *most* (but obviously not all) cases.

Comment: @Synetech: There's a little more to the procedures described at the link I posted, as well as other links.

Comment: I must be blind because the only links I see are in the MVP’s answer, the first one of which is a meaningless generic catch-all, the second says to use Windows Repair (again, already done), and the third says to run memtest (also a generic catch-all). Only the last link is at all relevant, in which case you should have linked directly to that instead of to another page that links to it (among a bunch of clutter).

Comment: @Synetech: Well, excuse me, _I_ felt it was important to read the instructions in context (and that the OP was perfectly capable of skipping any they had already done).

Comment: Well the instructions you linked to are not very helpful because they are a generic catch-all for general Windows trouble-shooting that MS MVPs seem to post to *every* question on the the MS forums. (Which is why only three of the 14 people who responded to that thread marked it as “helpful” and most even specifically said that the MVP’s instructions did not fix it.)

Comment: @Synetech: Ah, yes, all part of the context. Notice too that in my answer I said "might work". Perhaps part of the reason the MS support people constantly repeat those things is because it's using basic stuff built into Windows that everyone should make sure they've at least tried.

Comment: @Synetech OK, don't argue. ;)  I tried **everything** on that linked page.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer in most cases... Therefore I am accepting it.

Comment: http://www.dslreports.com/shownews/Kaspersky-AV-Breaking-CHKDSK-85517 - Did you have Kasperksy AV installed on your system?