# What do I need to do with a new harddrive in an old laptop to get it up and running again?

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite A505-s6960 that I bought almost 4 years ago. I have had problems with it. Today I took it in to my computer guy. he said that the harddrive is shot and to send it to forensics it may cost 500.00 to 5000.00.

Needless to say I had a new hard drive installed for 90.00 total. However when I turn it on I get:

```
"No bootable device--insert boot disk and press any key".
```

Again its a brand new drive that I got today.

Now what should I install on this beast? Where can I find this stuff and is it free? How do I do it? I am not a computer guy in fact I don't even know how many bits this beast is? and what Windows I should be installing on it?

ANY help would be more than greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me get this straight... a computer shop sold you a hard drive, but they didn't even try to recover anything, and they didn't re-install your OS for you? It sounds to me like you got a bad deal...

Comment: Anyways, there should be a sticker on the bottom of your laptop with the Windows version and a license key. Assuming it's Windows 7, [download the appropriate ISO](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) then [create a bootable flash drive](http://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive) to install Windows.

Comment: I realise this may be a year too late, but I would've taken it back to them, pointed at the screen and said 'this doesn't fix anything, where's Windows?'