# Unable to install/repair Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

Here is my System Specs:

Dell Inspiron N5010
4GB RAM
Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit OS

I was just starting the computer the other day and it gave me a blue screen immediately after Windows Loading screen.

```
UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME

TECHNICAL INFORMATION:
*** STOP: 0x000000ED
```

So I decided to reinstall the OS. But it is stuck at "Setup is Loading" Screen for hours together. I can't even repair the OS.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried a different CD or maybe an usb installation? http://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive

Answer (score 0):

You need to repair a filesystem - `chkdsk c: /f`
To do this you need to boot system from LiveCD, or plug your HDD into another computer.

Here is Microsoft article about this problem - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297185/en-us